# Need help combining formulas into a multiple IF statement

Tags: excel-formula

I'm having trouble writing a formula that will work and was hoping someone could offer assistance with something that requires multiple IF's.

Formula in J4 and J6: =($A$2-F6+1)/($A$2-DATE(YEAR($A$2),1,0))

Formula in J5: =(G5-DATE(YEAR(G5),1,0))/(A2-DATE(YEAR(A2),1,0))

What I want is a formula that can combine the two above formulas, with a max of 1.

IF Column G is Blank, then I want the formula from J4 and J6 with the number capped at 1.

IF Column G is NOT Blank, then my formula from J5.

I keep getting errors whenever I attempt to write this with multiple IF's in the same statement.

I want one formula that would yield 1 on J4, .344444 on J5, and .65555 on J6.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=MIN(1,IF(G4<>"",(G4-DATE(YEAR(G4),1,0))/($A$2-DATE(YEAR($A$2),1,0)),($A$2-F4+1)/($A$2-DATE(YEAR($A$2),1,0))))
```

[image]